# c++ - Does #pragma once work on different Operating Systems?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, operating-system, pragma

In C++ 11, #pragma once is not part of the standard but it's widely supported. The following wikipedia link says most major compilers (GCC, Clang, etc) support it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

My computer is a 64-bit Windows machine. With my compiler (GCC), #pragma once compiles. My question is whether #pragma once would also work on other major Operating Systems (Apple, Linux, and Android), given that the same compiler is used.

I'm sure there are exceptions on each OS, but I'm just wondering about whether #pragma once works on standard computers for each OS.

Comment: It's compiler-dependent, not OS-dependent.

Comment: The only major compiler that doesn't support it is the Portland Group compiler (which does support C++11):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability

Comment: There are also ways to foil the compiler.  If you have soft linked directories, or hard linked directories, and same-named header files in your project, you may be able to trick the compiler into reading in a header twice, or not reading in a header file it thought it already had read in.  The solution may seem to be "well, don't do that!", but sometimes a mature projects directory structures has accrued some oddities over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pragma is compiler dependent, if you use a compiler with support, it will work.

But for the moment, the usual recommendation is to use "pragma once" with headers guards.

This manner you ensure to include the file only once, and if pragma works, the compilation time will be improved.

Comment: "The major compilers" that support pragma once also know about include guards, and treat them the same. There is no advantage in using both.

Comment: @BoPersson -- "treat them the same" -- I hope not. You could, for example, use the same include guard in two different files; `#pragma once` would get this wrong. Or you could fool `pragma once` with two copies of the same file in two different locations.

Comment: @Pete - With "the same" I mean that the compilers will remember which files have include guards and check if those macros are still defined, without rereading the files. Also adding a pragma once to try to improve compile speed buys you nothing. But you are right that both methods can fail, and in *different* ways.